# Php: Set default drop down value in a loop

Tags: php, loops, database-design, default-value, html-select

A drop down list is printed in php in a while loop by taking value from database table. Here is the code:

```
  <select name='supervisor' class='form-control' name='supervisor'>
  <?php
  $sql = "SELECT username FROM system_user where type='supervisor'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['username'] ."'>" . $row['username'] ."</option>";}?>
  </select>
```

How can I set a default value for this? There is one 'username' value that i want to make as the default value. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name='supervisor' class='form-control' name='supervisor'>
  <?php
      $sql = "SELECT username FROM system_user where type='supervisor'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql); 
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $sel = ''; if($row['username'] == 'usename'){ $sel = 'selected'; }
          echo "<option $sel value='" . $row['username'] ."'>" . $row['username'] ."</option>";
      } ?>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function dropDown(array $array, $default = null, $select_attrs = '')
{

     $s = '<select $select_attr>';
     foreach((array)$array as $k => &$v) {
          $default = ($v === $default) ? 'selected' : null;
          $s.='<option '.$default.' >'.$v.'</option>';
     }
     return $s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this one worked for me...

```
<select name='supervisor' class='form-control' name='supervisor'>


<?php
  $sql = "SELECT username FROM system_user where type='supervisor'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $sel = ''; if($row['username'] == 'usename'){ $sel = 'selected'; }
      echo "<option $sel value='" . $row['username'] ."'>" . $row['username'] ."</option>";
  } ?>
```